# How to put text on a img html

Tags: html, jsp

I want to place a dynamic text on an img tag html like below(edited manually)

![enter image description here][1]

As shown below. I have tried to add text but its coming beside the image.Please help how can i do that.

My Code:

```
  <div style="float: left; display: inline-block; background: url('images/titlebar.png'); width: 287px; height: 32px">
My Profile
 </div>
```

Extra Space after image with Moorthy's edit:

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background property in css like: `background: url('images/titlebar.png');`

```
<div style="float: left; display: inline-block; background: url('images/titlebar.png') no-repeat; width: 287px; height: 32px">
    My Profile
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited few things.. Please try with last edit

Comment: there is some extra space coming after image as i edited my ticket.

Comment: please adjust width and height to make your button fit

Comment: use `no-repeat` in background `background: url('images/titlebar.png') no-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="" style="position: relative;"><span style="position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;">My profile</span></img>
```

You can try this - Set position: relative for parent and position: absolute for the text

Answer (score 0):

You need to set position relative to the image and position absolute to the text. More details can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/